# CoffeeScript in Chirpy Without Minification

Tags: coffeescript, chirpy

I have a foo.chirp.coffee while; by default, whenever I save, Chirpy both compiles the CoffeeScript to foo.js, and minifies that JavaScript to foo.min.js.

There are settings to use different minifiers depending on the name of the file, but during development I would not like to minify at all, in order to make debugging easier and to avoid the web service / external tool hit. I am probably missing something obvious but I do not see a way to do this. I have tried creating a config file with Minify="False" for my scripts, but it is still trying to perform the minification.

Is there any way of setting Chirpy to just output the JavaScript for my CoffeeScript without also minifying it? I am using Chirpy 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your project is set up, but perhaps you could just use the normal coffeescript compiler in --watch mode to compile your script while you're debugging.